# Ajax return automatic ordering number named arrays

Tags: javascript, ajax

So, i have a problem where my javascript is auto ordering number named arrays.

My object comes from an Ajax call, so i cant build it differently.

Example of my problem:

```
var test = {"1": "test1", "0": "test2", "2": "test3"}
```

output

```
console.log(test);

// {0: "teste2", 1: "teste1", 2: "teste3"}
```

The order should be 1,0,2...

Any way to solve this?

Btw, this is an example, in the script i am getting an object throw ajax and when i console.log it, it orders automatic, so map() functions wouldn't work here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show original order of object properties in console.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054764/show-original-order-of-object-properties-in-console-log)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key order is not always guaranteed with objects. The [default order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38218582/1762224) of properties when printing an object are as follows:

- Integer-like keys in ascending order
- String keys in insertion order
- Symbols in insertion order

In your example, below, the integer-like keys are sorted numerically in the consoles JSON result.

```js
const test = { "1": "test1", "0": "test2", "2": "test3" };

console.log(test); // {"0": "test2", "1": "test1", "2": "test3"}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If you want to preserve the order of the keys, you will need to store the key order and reference it when sorting the entries inside a custom JSON stringification function. If you only want to sort by the value, this is much simpler, because there is no need for a key order array.

```js
const test = { "1": "test1", "0": "test2", "2": "test3" };
const keyOrder = [ 1, 0, 2 ];

// Sorted by referenced key order
const customJsonStr = (obj, indent = '  ') =>
  `{\n${Object.entries(obj)
    .sort(([ka], [kb]) => keyOrder[ka] - keyOrder[kb])
    .map(([k, v]) => `${indent}"${k}": "${v}"`).join(',\n')}\n}`

// Sorted by value only
const customJsonStr2 = (obj, indent = '  ') =>
  `{\n${Object.entries(obj)
    .sort(([ka, va], [kb, vb]) => va.localeCompare(vb))
    .map(([k, v]) => `${indent}"${k}": "${v}"`).join(',\n')}\n}`

console.log(customJsonStr(test));  // {"1": "test1", "0": "test2", "2": "test3"}
console.log(customJsonStr2(test)); // {"1": "test1", "0": "test2", "2": "test3"}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: the keys are generated automatic, i dont know them, thats why i had to use an example, i had to add a string to the number to prevent that... =/

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` is automatically ordering the output, your JavaScript array itself won't be ordered, unless you call the higher-order function `Array.prototype.sort`

Comment: There is no array here. What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: If i create a FOR to show an alert, it will show the wrong order either.
`for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(test).length; i++) {
    alert(Object.keys(test)[i]);  
}
`

Comment: @LucasMartini please check the duplicates at the top of the page. Integer keys are enumerated in ascending order irrespective of the order they are inserted

Comment: but its not duplicate, the object comes from an ajax call, so i cant use their answers because its a different situation, i cant simply use a map() to not order the object.