# firebase firestore timestamp out of range

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

If I do: `new firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()` and use `console.log()` on it, the console prints out the following:

> {"nanoseconds": 89000000, "seconds": 1631289143}

If I now take those nanoseconds and seconds and try to create out of that the same timestamp like this: `new firebase.firestore.Timestamp(89000000, 1631289143)` I receive the error:

> FirebaseError: Timestamp nanoseconds out of range: 1631289143

Can someone pls explain this strange behavior to me? How is it possible that I cannot recreate the timestamp from just few seconds ago?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are swapping the values: The second argument passed to the [Timestamp constructor](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#constructor) shall be the `nanoseconds` (89000000 in your example) but, instead, you pass the value of `seconds` (1631289143 in your example, which is out of the allowed range, i.e. 0 to 999,999,999 inclusive).

You should do

```
new firebase.firestore.Timestamp(1631289143, 89000000);
```

You probably did the error because `console.log` [sorts the object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054764/show-original-order-of-object-properties-in-console-log)...

Comment: Indeed `console.log()` messed up my understanding of the Timestamp Object. 

It really switched nanoseconds with seconds and still does when I print it out in my console, but thx to your answer I was able to understand and overcome this problem!