# Why Keys of Object are sorted alphabetically in React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I encountered a problem that the object I created is sorting the keys in alphabetical order.
This sorting happens only in my React Native project not when I run usual js file or  browser console.

```
let obj = {
    b:1,
    a:2
}
console.log(obj) // {"a": 2, "b": 1}
```

I tried using Map() and then converted to Object but still keys are sorting itself.
What is the reason behind it and how to fix it?

Version:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.66.2
node: v16.13.0

Comment: Objects are not meant to store data in sequentially, If you want to store data sequentially then you should use Array or Map. Both preserve the order of insertion

Comment: But it is sorting the keys in my project only not in a normal js file or browser console it's not random and I wanted to know that why it is happening and how to prevent it

Comment: *"I tried using Map() and then converted to Object"* why? was there an issue with the Map? A Map would guarantee the order.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57701452/476…

Comment: I don't know react-native, but i don't see it altering node's behavior much (if at all), and i can't reproduce the described `console.log` behavior on node.