# How to return one JavaScript object value before another

Tags: javascript-objects

Working my way through the FreeCodeCamp website.

**Task:**

The variable watchList holds an array of objects with information on several movies. Use a combination of filter and map on watchList to assign a new array of objects with only title and rating keys. The new array should only include objects where imdbRating is greater than or equal to 8.0. Note that the rating values are saved as strings in the object and you may need to convert them into numbers to perform mathematical operations on them.

**Provided code**

```
// The global variable
const watchList = [
  {
    "Title": "Inception",
    "Year": "2010",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "16 Jul 2010",
    "Runtime": "148 min",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Crime",
    "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
    "Writer": "Christopher Nolan",
    "Actors": "Leonardo DiCaprio, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Elliot Page, Tom Hardy",
    "Plot": "A thief, who steals corporate secrets through use of dream-sharing technology, is given the inverse task of planting an idea into the mind of a CEO.",
    "Language": "English, Japanese, French",
    "Country": "USA, UK",
    "Awards": "Won 4 Oscars. Another 143 wins & 198 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjAxMzY3NjcxNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTI5OTM0Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "74",
    "imdbRating": "8.8",
    "imdbVotes": "1,446,708",
    "imdbID": "tt1375666",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Interstellar",
    "Year": "2014",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "07 Nov 2014",
    "Runtime": "169 min",
    "Genre": "Adventure, Drama, Sci-Fi",
    "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
    "Writer": "Jonathan Nolan, Christopher Nolan",
    "Actors": "Ellen Burstyn, Matthew McConaughey, Mackenzie Foy, John Lithgow",
    "Plot": "A team of explorers travel through a wormhole in space in an attempt to ensure humanity's survival.",
    "Language": "English",
    "Country": "USA, UK",
    "Awards": "Won 1 Oscar. Another 39 wins & 132 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjIxNTU4MzY4MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzM4ODI3MjE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "74",
    "imdbRating": "8.6",
    "imdbVotes": "910,366",
    "imdbID": "tt0816692",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True"
  },
  {
    "Title": "The Dark Knight",
    "Year": "2008",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "18 Jul 2008",
    "Runtime": "152 min",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Crime",
    "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
    "Writer": "Jonathan Nolan (screenplay), Christopher Nolan (screenplay), Christopher Nolan (story), David S. Goyer (story), Bob Kane (characters)",
    "Actors": "Christian Bale, Heath Ledger, Aaron Eckhart, Michael Caine",
    "Plot": "When the menace known as the Joker wreaks havoc and chaos on the people of Gotham, the caped crusader must come to terms with one of the greatest psychological tests of his ability to fight injustice.",
    "Language": "English, Mandarin",
    "Country": "USA, UK",
    "Awards": "Won 2 Oscars. Another 146 wins & 142 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTMxNTMwODM0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODAyMTk2Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "82",
    "imdbRating": "9.0",
    "imdbVotes": "1,652,832",
    "imdbID": "tt0468569",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Batman Begins",
    "Year": "2005",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "15 Jun 2005",
    "Runtime": "140 min",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure",
    "Director": "Christopher Nolan",
    "Writer": "Bob Kane (characters), David S. Goyer (story), Christopher Nolan (screenplay), David S. Goyer (screenplay)",
    "Actors": "Christian Bale, Michael Caine, Liam Neeson, Katie Holmes",
    "Plot": "After training with his mentor, Batman begins his fight to free crime-ridden Gotham City from the corruption that Scarecrow and the League of Shadows have cast upon it.",
    "Language": "English, Urdu, Mandarin",
    "Country": "USA, UK",
    "Awards": "Nominated for 1 Oscar. Another 15 wins & 66 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNTM3OTc0MzM2OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNzUwMTI3._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "70",
    "imdbRating": "8.3",
    "imdbVotes": "972,584",
    "imdbID": "tt0372784",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True"
  },
  {
    "Title": "Avatar",
    "Year": "2009",
    "Rated": "PG-13",
    "Released": "18 Dec 2009",
    "Runtime": "162 min",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Fantasy",
    "Director": "James Cameron",
    "Writer": "James Cameron",
    "Actors": "Sam Worthington, Zoe Saldana, Sigourney Weaver, Stephen Lang",
    "Plot": "A paraplegic marine dispatched to the moon Pandora on a unique mission becomes torn between following his orders and protecting the world he feels is his home.",
    "Language": "English, Spanish",
    "Country": "USA, UK",
    "Awards": "Won 3 Oscars. Another 80 wins & 121 nominations.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTYwOTEwNjAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODc5MTUwMw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Metascore": "83",
    "imdbRating": "7.9",
    "imdbVotes": "876,575",
    "imdbID": "tt0499549",
    "Type": "movie",
    "Response": "True"
  }
];
```

**My code**

```
var filteredList = watchList
  .map(movie => ({
      title: movie.Title,
      rating: movie.imdbRating

  }))
  .filter(movie => {
   movie.rating = +movie.rating;
    return movie.rating >= 8.0;
  });
console.log(filteredList);
```

**Console:**

```
[{
  rating: 8.8,
  title: "Inception"
}, {
  rating: 8.6,
  title: "Interstellar"
}, {
  rating: 9,
  title: "The Dark Knight"
}, {
  rating: 8.3,
  title: "Batman Begins"
}]
```

**I need to display the titles before the ratings in the console, how can I swap these around, please? So I get the following instead:**

```
[{
  title: "Inception",
  rating: 8.8
  }, {
  title: "Interstellar",
  rating: 8.6 
}, {
  title: "The Dark Knight",
  rating: 9
}, {
  title: "Batman Begins",
  rating: 8.3
}]
```

Comment: Maybe `console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredList))` will preserve the order of entries?

Comment: @NaphatAmundsen Thank-you, that seems to work. I'm trying to understand why the order changes?

Comment: I believe it is due to implementation details in some browsers (e.g. Chrome). This does not happen in node. This behavior of `console.log` is not something you should rely on as of now. This post has some answers around this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054764/show-original-order-of-object-properties-in-console-log